# Getting There’s no page at this address when trying to install app on the store Shopify Laravel App Osiset

Tags: php, laravel-8, shopify-app

I am new in shopify app development and trying to create a public app in laravel using Shopify Laravel App using [Osiset/laravel](https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify). I installed NGROK and is running fine. Added the NGROK URL in the APP configuration settings on shopify store and also added the same in the `APP_URL` variable of ENV file.

For the first time APP got installed successfully but when I uninstalled the APP from the store and again trying to install it, I am getting the error of `Getting There’s no page at this address`. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Is there something like I can install app only once? Do I need to create a new store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix. I am posting here in case someone face the same issue. As the app was installed successfully once. An entry of the store URL was stored in the DB due to which it was not authenticating again. I deleted  the entry from `users` table of the APP database and it worked!